# android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED is not auto populating in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I want to add `<action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED"/>` However this is not getting auto populated in **Android Studio 3.3.1**
However `android.intent.action.AIRPLANE_MODE` is getting autopopulated.
In order to avoid typo error is there *anyway I can get this validated in manifest file*

Answer (score 1):

The Telephony class does not have a documented API until API 19 (4.4 - KitKat). The absence of the class does not mean what you are trying to do does not work. You need to request this permission:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS"/>
```